# How can I remove word count in Tiny MCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

How can I remove word count in TinyMCE?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing a word count in the status bar you are loading the `wordcount` plugin in your TinyMCE configuration.  If you remove `wordcount` from your `plugins` list in the configuration you will no longer see that in the statusbar.